# Should i partion 100% of my san's HDD's or leave some unused?

Tags: windows, storage-area-network, utilization

I am new to posting here but have been reading and utilizing your extreme brains over the years so Thank you all for being so generous!!

I just bought a new Synology NAS for my domain and i am setting it up and i remember one of my old vendors many years ago said to never fully utilize my maximum SAN Storage because if i ever ran out of HDD Space i had the ability to expand and drives and bring it back online quickly.

I am not sure if that matters any more or if i am mixing up information so i figured i would ask you all and double check my thinking.

My configuration will be the synology will be an iScsi target for my 2019 server. Currently i have it setup at maximum size thick provisioned.

Any help or thoughts would be greatly appreciated

Steven

Answer (score 0):

SAN are storage area networks, what you have is a NAS. Don't want to sound picky, but let's not mix up stuff up.

We recommend people to refrain from using 100% of space mostly due to uncountable cases where people had to rush buying additional disks and work under pressure as some server stopped due to lack of space, had you used 95% of your disk's via iSCSI you could just release the last 5% and from there take your time to plan that storage's upgrade, it's a far easier storm, and working under pressure with storages is a common start for many IT horror stories.

As of today most/all NASses offer some sort of technology to expand your storage by adding disks, yet to use it you'd often have to setup it up beforehand, so consider creating an LVM/JBOD/RAID setup even if you're single disk right now, as long as your NAS have additional slots for future expansion it will be much easier to expand business.